# Moving inner circle tangentially to outer circle

Tags: c#, math, geometry

If two circles intersect, how can I move inner circle upwards on Y axis untill it becomes tangent to the outer circle

Comment: What are you asking? How to draw the circles? The maths to calculate how far to move it? Provide some more info about what you have tried so far and some of your code.

Comment: If I may ask, how exactly is this a C# question, apart from the fact that you might want to eventually code up this *maths* problem in that particular language?

Comment: @alpha-mouse: Not sure about that. I think Math Overflow is for advanced mathematical problems. What I meant to say is that the question is tagged in a mis-leading way. If I see a `c#` tag, I expect to deal with an issue in some particular bit of C# code. However, it seems the OP hasn't even to code yet. It would be good if s/he could at least provide some info where s/he's currently stuck.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the circles have radii `R1` and `R2`, assuming `R1 <= R2`, then they will be tangent when the distance between the centers `D` is `R2 - R1` or `R2 + R1`, depending on if you want one inside the other or not.  If `dx` is the x-distance between the centers, then you need

```
dy = sqrt( D * D - dx * dx )
```

Move one circle so that the y-distance between the centers is `dy`.  Note that if the circles don't intersect, `dy` will be complex and `sqrt` might throw an error.